# Python: Export multiple arrays using def and for loops for a range of values in a list

Tags: python, function, numpy

I have looked through multiple other threads on this topic, but I was not able to find anything that fit what I need. The end result I am trying to reach is numpy array of numbers for each number in a range. I have tried using for loops and python's def functionality to complete this, but I feel I may be missing a step. The code I have written so far is below.

```
source_values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21]

def CreateSourceList(z):
    y = []
    for i in z:
        Start = 3332
        n = 21
        End = 11733
        y = np.arange(Start + i, End, n)
    return y
```

The code creates a numpy array for each value in the source_values list and uses the source's value in the calculation of the array. However, when I use the new function (CreateSourceList), it will only return the numpy array for the last source value in the source_values list. So is there anyway to export a numpy array for each source value in the source_values list?

- For source_values = 1 the result should be [3333, 3354, 3375, 3396, ...]
- For source_values = 2 the result should be [3334, 3355, 3376, 3397, ...]
- For source_values = 3 the result should be [3335, 3356, 3377, 3398, ...]

Thanks!

Comment: You are over-writing the numpy array in `y` each iteration. You could try something like `y.append(np.arange(Start + i, End, n))`. Then y will be an array of all the numpy arrays you generate.

Comment: @Serial Thank you! I wasn't aware that I was overwriting y with every source value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use a list comprehension to generate your numbers.  Also, just add the offset `i` to your original range.

```
Start = 3332
n = 21
End = 3395
source_values = [1, 2, 3]

>>> [np.arange(Start, End, n) + i for i in source_values]
[array([3333, 3354, 3375]),
 array([3334, 3355, 3376]),
 array([3335, 3356, 3377])]
```

Comment: This is really close to my end goal. However, is there a way I can do this so that the arrays are separate? Rather than have all of the desired arrays in a larger array.

Comment: You can either unpack them to assign each one to a variable (e.g. `a1, a2, a3 = ...`), or else they need to be held in a collection of some kind (list, tuple, dict, etc).

Comment: Thanks for all of your help!